# How to access two different PHP sessions in the same PHP script?

Tags: php, session

I've tried this:

```
session_name('mys1');
session_start();
var_dump($_SESSION);

session_name('mys2');
session_start();
var_dump($_SESSION);
```

but both var_dumps dump the session 'mys1' data.

I've also tried putting a `session_destroy()` in between:

```
session_name('mys1');
session_start();
var_dump($_SESSION);

session_destroy();

session_name('mys2');
session_start();
var_dump($_SESSION);
```

that actually var_dumps the two different sessions correctly but after that the 'mys1' session is gone.

Comment: learn what `session_destroy();` function do..? what `session_destroy();` function do is its destroy the session from the script.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use different cookies for these different sessions.

When you call `session_start()` a cookie is created for that session.

Try to do `session_id($_COOKIE['session_two']);` before the second session_start() to jump to the correct session id

Comment: i tried calling `session_id()` but it didn't have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`session_write_close`](http://php.net/session_write_close) instead of `session_destroy`.